# How can I determine if a list of ranges covers a given range?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, search

I want to efficiently determine whether a list of ranges covers a given range. For example the list of ranges [(0-3), (3-5), (4-8), (6-10)] covers the range (0-10) while [(5-10), (0-3)] does not. The list can contain overlaps and is not necessarily ordered.

I tried to implement a `Continuous` function shown below which checks if the slice of byte ranges contains the given `start` and `end` of a passed range.

```golang
type byteRange struct {
    start int64
    end   int64
}

type byteRanges []*byteRange

func (brs byteRanges) Len() int {
    return len(brs)
}

func (brs byteRanges) Swap(i, j int) {
    brs[i], brs[j] = brs[j], brs[i]
}

func (brs byteRanges) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return brs[i].start < brs[j].start
}

func (brs byteRanges) Continuous(start int64, end int64) bool {
    curPos := start
    sort.Sort(brs)

    for _, br := range brs {
        if br.start > curPos+1 {
            return false
        }

        if curPos < br.end {
            curPos = br.end
        }

        if curPos >= end {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

The function behaves correctly but it is not very performant when working with a large list of ranges and when it is called often. Can somebody recommend an algorithm/implementation that can speed up this logic?

Comment: Are you repeatedly calling `Continuous` on the same slice of ranges? (I ask because, if so, it might be a good idea to some preprocessing.)

Comment: @ruakh yes I am repeatedly calling `Continuous` on the same slice of ranges. What preprocessing techniques are you thinking of? Clarification: there are multiple static ranges that I am calling `Continuous` with.

Comment: @tab1293 Preprocessing can reduce the list of ranges by combining overlapped/adjacent ranges. So given [(0,3), (4,8), (2,7), (10,16), (12,20)], you can preprocess the list to [(0,8), (10,20)]. And then, since the ranges in the preprocessed list don't overlap, you can binary search the list.

Answer (score 2):

Since you will repeatedly call `Continuous` on the same set of ranges, it's a good idea to create a `Condense` method (or whatever you wish to call it) that will take a slice and return a new slice with the ranges sorted and any overlapping ranges merged. You only need to call `Condense` *once* for any given set of ranges. `Continuous` can then require that it only be called on the result of `Condense`. (To enforce this requirement, it may be a good idea to have `Condense` actually return a `struct` of a custom type that's just a wrapper around a slice, and to define `Continuous` only on that `struct` type. If you want — as a convenience — you can then define a separate `Continuous` method that *can* be called directly on slices, that invokes `Condense` and then `Continuous`. That convenience method will be slow again, of course, but it may be convenient for sets that are only checked once.)

The merging logic in `Condense` is pretty simple:

- If the slice is empty, just return it (exiting early).
- Sort ranges by their `start`.
- Create a fresh slice called `result`.
- Initialize `prevRange` to the first range.
- Iterate over the ranges. For each one:

  - If the current range starts after `prevRange.end + 1`, add `prevRange` to `result`, then set `prevRange` to the current range.
  - Otherwise, if the current range ends after `prevRange.end`, set `prevRange.end` to the `end` of the current range.
- Add `prevRange` to `result`.

The logic in `Continuous` can now be:

- Perform a binary search over the ranges, finding the last range whose `start` is less than or equal to `start`.
- If this range's `end` is greater than or equal to `end`, return `true`; otherwise, return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that is more simple?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type byteRange struct {
    start int64
    end   int64
}

type byteRanges []*byteRange

func (brs byteRanges) Continuous(start int64, end int64) bool {
    sort.Slice(brs, func(i, j int) bool {
        return brs[i].start < brs[j].start
    })

    var (
        longestReach int64
        in           bool
    )

    for _, br := range brs {
        if !in {
            // first br satrts laying over the target
            if br.start <= start && br.end >= start {
                longestReach = br.end
                in = true
            }
            continue
        }
        if in && longestReach < br.start-1 {
            break
        }
        if longestReach < br.end {
            longestReach = br.end
        }
    }

    return in && longestReach >= end
}

func main() {
    brs := byteRanges{{5, 9}, {6, 10}}
    fmt.Println(brs.Continuous(8, 10))
}
```